# opencv. не выводится текст на фрейм из веб-камеры

Tags: python, opencv, pil

Делаю нейронную сеть по теме "распознание дорожных знаков". Не выводит текст после распознавания, точнее кириллицу  - пишет `???????`. На латинице все хорошо работает

```
 сv2.putText(modifiedFrame, signname, (spos.x, spos.y + spos.h + 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontScale=0.4, color=boxcolor, lineType=2)
```

пробовал

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191008/load-truetype-font-to-opencv

Comment: нашел ответ на англ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942605/how-to-use-unicode-characters-with-pil

Comment: чтобы использовать юникод

Comment: какой я молодец ))